# C pointers and accessing arrays

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

It's been a while since I've had to program in C and I have completely forgotten how to work with pointers. So for my project I have to make a program that reading in a txt file and create a histogram of the numbers.

The program must be

```
void hist_2d(
    int *head, /* A pointer to the input tiles. */
    int w, /* The width (in pixels) of the tile. */
    int h, /* The height (in pixels) of the tile. */
    int stride, /* Number of pixels between 2 contiguous rows. */
    int *bins, /* Array of input bins for the desired histogram. */
    int m, /* The number of input bins. */
    int *out /* An array in which to store the output histogram. */
)
```

My question is with *head and accessing the array.

So for example the image is

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6;
7,8,9,10,11,12;
13,14,15,16,17,18;
19,20,21,22,23,24]
```

In pixels.txt it would be:

```
1
2
3
...
```

The histogram is supposed to calculated in tiles, so for my example a tile could be a 2x3 which would be:

```
[1,2,3;
7,8,9]
```

Doing the histogram part is easy its getting they data that I don't understand. From what I understand *head is an array of addresses for the starting point of each tile but how do actually get the value? and how do I get the next value?

Would head[0] get me the address or the first value?

Thank you, sorry for the long post, but I wanted to make sure I gave all the info needed.

Comment: *From what I understand *head is an array of addresses* No. `*head` is an integer. `head` is a pointer to an integer. `head[0]` is equivalent to `*head`. If `head` is a pointer to a region of memory capable of holding more than one integer, then yes, you can treat it as an array and access the elements with the `[]` operator.

Comment: Do you have any code? It seems to me that your understanding is fine. Perhaps it would be more beneficial to write a sample program that does nothing but read in data from a file on disk and then attempt to access it.

Comment: I missed the quote from Filipe. He's completely correct. I would still suggest writing a simple program first. Seems like you're attempting to tackle the entire problem at once.

Answer (score 1):

Yeas, it sounds as if `head` is a pointer to the first element in an array of `int`, where each element is (perhaps) the index of the upper left corner of a tile. In your example of the 2x3 tiles (if whoever filled the array is using those numbers as indices), the array would contain [1, 4, 13, 16].

Here's how to handle the elements of an array:

```
int h[4];

h[0] = 1;
h[1] = 4;
h[2] = 13;
h[3] = 16;

printf("%d\n", h[0]);  // will print "1"

int n = h[2]; // the value of n is now 13
```

Does that clear things up?

Comment: Huh, I didn't see the `c++`-tag in the question... Wait, there isn't one! Also, `2*3 != 4`.

Comment: And, as pointed out above, it's not an array. It's a pointer.

Comment: @EOF: You're right about C/C++, force of habit, I'll edit. As for the indices, I guessed from the example that the OP was thinking in terms of 1-indexing for the image.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider: *What* is not an array, but a pointer? Do you mean `head`, which I referred to as a pointer?

Comment: head should be something like [&p[0],&p[4],...] the addresses of the left corner of each tile. What would I need to do to get p[1] from using head? and how would I get the value of p[0]? if p is the big matrix from my original post

Comment: @TylerM: Hold on, if `p` is the thing you called "the image", then how is it implemented? If we infer from the commas and semicolons that it's a 2-dimensional array (e.g. `int p[4][6]`), then the address of an element within it will have the form of *two*  numbers, not one.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear. pixels.txt will be a 1-d array and be read in like a 1-d array. The 2-d array way to show how tiles would be set up.

Comment: @TylerM: So how would `p` be implemented? As a 1D array (e.g. `int p[24]`) or as a 2D array (e.g. `int p[4][6]`) or what? Note that `pixels.txt` is a file, not an array.

Comment: So pixels.txt will be read in and put into a 1d array p. From there a hist_2d will be called like in my original post, which should be able to get all the values based on the addresses of the top left corner of each tile, and then organize them based off the other inputs. Sorry, I've had a pretty big headache all day and I'm definitely not thinking straight today.

Comment: What you're asking for seems to be different from what you want. Maybe we should try another day.